# Find a set of complex numbers for equation $2|z|<|1+z^2|$ and draw it

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

Find a set of complex numbers for equation $2|z|<|1+z^2|$ and draw it.

That's as far as I got:
$$4x^2+4y^2<(x^2+y^2+1)^2+x^2y^2\\
\vdots\\
x^4+y^4-6x^2-2y^2+1>0\\
(x^2-3)^2+(y^2-1)^2>9$$

Now I have no idea how to draw this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine the set of points $z$ that satisfy the condition $|2z|>|1+z^2|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126953/determine-the-set-of-points-z-that-satisfy-the-condition-2z1z2) – just take the complement!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2149074/42969

Answer (score 0):

$2\vert z \vert <\,\vert 1+z^2\vert \,<\,1+\vert z \vert ^2 $
$$ \vert z \vert ^2 -2\vert z \vert +1>0$$
$$(\vert z \vert -1)^2>0$$
$$\vert z \vert \ge 0 \,\,and \vert z \vert \neq 1 $$